# VueJS use EventBus in mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

Here my code :

A random component :

```
watch: {
          'notifications' : {
            handler(newVal) {
              let questionnaireTypes = ['TwoDaysConnected', 'OneWeekConnected', 'TwoWeekInactive']
              if(newVal) {
                this.checkDisplayQuestionnaire(questionnaireTypes)
              }
            },
            immediate: false
          }
        },
```

The method in mixin_common.js :

```
    import EventBus from "./event-bus.js"

export default window.mixin_common = {
    methods: {
        checkDisplayQuestionnaire(questionnaireTypes) {
          let stateNotifications = this.$store.state.notifications
          EventBus.$emit('openQuestionnaireExperimentationModalWithDatas', 
          stateNotifications)
        }
    }
```

The component where is the modal i want to open with the EventBus :

```
import EventBus from "./event-bus.js"

     methods: {
        openModal() {
          this.$bvModal.show('questionnaireExperimentationModal')
        },
      },
      mounted() {
        EventBus.$on('openQuestionnaireExperimentationModalWithDatas', (notifications) => {
          this.notifications = notifications
          this.openModal()
        })
```

Event-bus.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const EventBus = new Vue();

export default EventBus;
```

Actually, the modal does not open, the only way it works is when i place the `EventBus.$emit('openQuestionnaireExperimentationModalWithDatas', stateNotifications)` directly in the random component, without using the mixin, but i need to open it with the mixin if it's possible.

Anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: Did you check if  `openModal` is called or not?

Comment: @Anatoly openModal is not called

Comment: @TonyS Can you check if mixin is imported porperly, Can you check if the flow reaches the method `checkDisplayQuestionnaire` ?